# A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

> THERE ARE 2 ERRORS IN THIS PROGRAM WHICH HAVE BEEN SHOWN IN THE IMAGES ABOVE

Main.dart file

```
void main() {
 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Personal Expenses ',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        //errorColor: Colors.red[700],
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            title: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber)),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                title: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
   
  ];
  bool _showChart = false;
  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
      return tx.date.isAfter(
        DateTime.now().subtract(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  void _addNewTransaction(
      String txTitle, double txAmount, DateTime chosenDate) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: chosenDate,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.removeWhere((tx) => tx.id == id);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    final PreferredSizeWidget appbar = Platform.isIOS
```

> A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.

```
        ? CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text(
              'Personal Expenses ',
            ),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
                  onTap: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        : AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Personal Expenses ',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
              ),
            ],
          );
    final txListWidget = Container(
      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
              appbar.preferredSize.height -
              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
          0.7,
      child: TransactionList(
        _userTransactions,
        _deleteTransaction,
      ),
    );
    final pageBody = SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (isLandscape)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Show Chart'),
                Switch.adaptive(
                  activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  value: _showChart,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showChart = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
         
        ],
      ),
    );
```

return Platform.isIOS
? CupertinoPageScaffold(
child: pageBody,
navigationBar: appbar,

> The argument type 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget?'.

```
          )
        : Scaffold(
            .........,
                  ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: When giving code samples please include the whole file in one code chunk to make it easier to reproduce your issue. You can always add errors as comments in the code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code works in non-null safe versions of Flutter. I do not know why the null safe version now objects to:

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appbar = Platform.isIOS ...
```

If you omit the type:

```
final appbar = Platform.isIOS ...
```

Then `appbar` is interpreted as a `Widget` and gives an error on `appbar.preferredSize`.

You can force the type to be examined at runtime:

```
final dynamic appbar = Platform.isIOS ...
```

This works for me testing with my Android device. However, I have not tested with an Apple device.

I created this [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81969) for the change in behaviour with the null-safe version of flutter. You can subscribe to the issue to get update notifications.

**Edit:**
The Flutter team raised a [Dart issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45941) which explains the new bahaviour and suggests using:

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appbar = (Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar()) 
                                   as PreferredSizeWidget;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. Don't mistake me if I mention you in further questions of mine to answer and I'll make sure the posted code is easy to reproduce. Once again thanks

Comment: If i change the code according to what you have mentioned in the edit i am getting this error 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395364/the-getter-preferredsize-isnt-defined-for-the-type-widget
The argument type 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget?'

Comment: When you use `appbar` later you can downcast it, i.e. `navigationBar: appbar as ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget`.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, this is due to the null safety feature of Dart

Solution

```
final dynamic appBar = Platform.isIOS
    ? CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar()
```

Or you can use

```
final PreferredSizedWidget appBar = Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoNavigationBar() as ObstructingPreferredSizedWidget : AppBar()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, appBar accept `widget` that implements `PreferredSize`

and CupertinoPageScaffold accept widget that implements  ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget

so `don't determine` the datatype of the appbar

and let it be determined at the runtime.

**simply make** it like this

```
final appBar = Platform.IOS ?  CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar()
```

and add the CupertinoNavigationBar in CupertinoPageScaffold

and add the AppBar to Scaffold

Comment: This doesn't seem to work sir ,if i remove the PreferredSizeWidget im getting another error 
The getter 'preferredSize' isn't defined for the type 'Widget'.