# The getter 'preferredSize' isn't defined for the type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: error 1]

[image: Errors]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    final appBar = Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text(
              'Personal Expenses',
            ),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
                  onTap: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Personal Expenses',
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
              ),
            ],
          );
```

> The getter 'preferredSize' isn't defined for the type 'Widget'.

```
    final txListWidget = Container(
      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
              appBar.preferredSize.height -
              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
          0.7,
```

> The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget?'

```
 return Platform.isIOS
    ? CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: pageBody,
        navigationBar: appBar,
      )
```

> The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

```
: Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: pageBody,
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the code into the following format.

```dart
final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = (Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoNavigationBar(...) : AppBar(...)) as PreferredSizeWidget;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use data type for the variable appBar

```
final PreferredSizeWidge appBar = Platform.isIOS ? ......
```

Comment: ,if it use that data type 'PreferredSizeWidget' im getting another error
A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.

Comment: `CupertinoNavigationBar` is not a `PreferredSizeWidget`. you can change the AppBar properties to get the IOS native feel, Otherwise you will have to use `CupertinoPageScaffold` for `CupertinoNavigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

Change `appbar` type from `PreferredSizeWidget` or `Widget` to `dynamic`

Answer (score 0):

Add the type of appbar as dynamic. this error comes because dart cannot understand that preferredsize class is defined for both cupertionoappwidget and appbar.

Solution : final dynamic appbar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Full Solution of your error

```html
    final appBar = (Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoNavigationBar(...) : AppBar(...));

final txListWidget = Container(
        height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                (appBar as PreferredSizeWidget).preferredSize.height -
                mediaQuery.padding.top) *
            0.77,
        child: TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction));


return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageScaffold(
            navigationBar: appBar as ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget,
            child: pageBody,
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(child: pageBody), .....
```